# How to check whether a number exists in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether a number exists in given array or not?The number I've decided tomcheck for is "7" and I want to get it even if it's as a part of a number. e.g, 97...
I'm a newbie to javascript so, would really appreciate if someone could explain the solution in details... I've also attached my sample of code as well.

```js
function sevenBoom(arr) {
  let singleElement;
  let string;
  let includeSeven;

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    singleElement = arr[i];
    string = singleElement.toString();
    includeSeven = string.includes("7");
  }
  if (includeSeven == true){
    return "Boom!"
  }else{
    return "There is no 7 in the array";
  }
}

arr = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let result = sevenBoom(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `arr.some(a => a.toString().includes(7));`

`some()` will be efficient more efficient as it will stop at the first matching condition and won't go further to check rest of the values in the array. Use `.toString()` to convert `number` to `string` and then we can use `includes` to check if values present in that string or not. Further details regarding to methods are provided below.

- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) : The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.
- [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) : The `includes()` method performs a case-sensitive search to determine whether one string may be found within another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.
- [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) : The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Try it below.

```js
let arr = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let result = arr.some(a => a.toString().includes(7));
console.log(result);

let arr2 = [1,97];
let result2 = arr2.some(a => a.toString().includes(7));
console.log(result2);

let arr3 = [1,6];
let result3 = arr3.some(a => a.toString().includes(7));
console.log(result3)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions that would work. I am discussing an approach which is quite simple to understand.

```js
function sevenBoom(arr) {
  // Initial array: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  // "map" will convert the number array to string array
  // Array after map: ["1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  // "join" will join all the string numbers
  // Joined string: "12456789"
  // "includes" will check if "7" is in the joined string
  const hasSeven = arr.map(n => `${n}`).join("").includes("7");
  return hasSeven ? "Boom!" : "There is no 7 in the array";
};

let result = sevenBoom([1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
console.log(result);
result = sevenBoom([1,97]);
console.log(result);
result = sevenBoom([1,2]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You need to use ``${n}`` instead of ``n``

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that, you have to exit the for loop execution, when you find an occurance of seven, else it will iterate the complete array and your variable `includeSeven` will holds only the last comparison result.

Here your loop will run against each element in the array `arr`. When the loop executes the element `7` in the array, it will set `includeSeven` as true. But the loop executes further and eveluates the rest of elements `8` and `9`. So `includeSeven` will be holding the result of last execution. So you should exit the loop when you have got a match.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function sevenBoom(arr) {
  let singleElement;
  let string;
  let includeSeven;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    singleElement = arr[i];
    string = singleElement.toString();
    includeSeven = string.includes("7");
    if (includeSeven) {
      i = arr.length; // Implementation of break
    }
  }
  if (includeSeven == true) {
    return "Boom!"
  } else {
    return "There is no 7 in the array";
  }
}

arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(sevenBoom(arr));
```

**OR**

Simple One line function that checks there is any element in the array having `7` as a digit somewhere in the elements using `Array.some` and `String.includes`.

Here [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will check if at least one element in the array matches the condition that we specify. [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) whether the orr string includes a specific element. So we check any one the element in array has a string 7

**Working Fiddle**

```js
sevenBoom = (arr) => arr.some((item) => item.toString().includes("7")) ? "Boom!" : "There is no 7 in the array";
arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(sevenBoom(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy-peasy, there is code:

```js
function sevenBoom(arr) {
  if(arr.join().includes(7)||arr.join().includes('7')) return 'Boom!'
  else return 'No 7 in array :('
}
sevenBoom([1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

I used ES6+ Syntax, so you can easily understand how everything works :)

MDN Links:
[`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
[`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: As per the question `I want to get it even if it's as a part of a number. e.g, 97`. Your code will not handle this condition correctly. Also you can combine `arr.findIndex(num => num === 7) > 0||arr.findIndex(num => num === '7') > 0` with one condition using `==` as `arr.findIndex(num => num == 7) > 0`.

Comment: @Karan fixed code, I didn't really have seen actual question :p

Answer (score 0):

If the input array consists of real numbers, convert them into strings because there's math involved with getting a 7 out of 1083.703 but it's easy to get a "7" out of "1053.703". Use `.filter()` to iterate through the array and `.includes()` as the callback.

```js
const seven = [0, 100.7, 8, 9, 55, -63, 7, 99, -57];

function findChar(char, array) {
  return array.filter(num => num.toString().includes(char));
}

console.log(findChar('7', seven));
```